# undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass -- field is NOT nil in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a Rails app with a field called `end_date` which is required for a record to be saved to the database.

In another part of the app, I am converting the end_date field's output using

```
<%= end_date.strftime('%b %d, %Y') %>
```

However, I am receiving the error

```
undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass
```

In reference to the line of code above. This error is (as far as I've found so far) only occurring on one record in the database, which has a value of `2018-12-21` for the end_date in the database.

---

When I login to the Rails console and load the same record from the database, then call `end_date.strftime('%b %d, %Y')` on the record, it returns

```
=> "Dec 21, 2018"
```

As expected.

This error is only occurring for one record, and it is not because the method is being called on a null record, which is what the error message says is the cause.

I have looked into some other solutions, but I do not have a `default_timezone` set in `application.rb`, so I don't think it's an error being caused by that.

For reference I am using devise to handle authentication, if that matters.

I'm nearing my wit's end, does anyone have any ideas as to what might be causing this error?

Comment: Where do you set `end_date`? Have you tried doing `<%= end_date %>`? Just to see that it is, in fact, not nil as you suggest?

Comment: How are you calling `end_date`? where is it assigned? Shouldn't you be calling the attribute `end_date` on the instance?

Comment: `end_date` is input by users using a datepicker.. I tried calling just `<%= end_date %>` and it rendered in the view as `2018-12-21`

Comment: I tried wrapping it in a `try` and changing it to `end_date.try(:strftime, '%b %d, %Y')` and that actually works and renders the date exactly as expected. I'm still not sure why this would only be necessary for one record that isn't even nil...

Comment: Assuming you are using Ruby 2.3+, you should use `end_date&.strftime('%b %d, %Y')` instead of `end_date.try(:strftime, '%b %d, %Y')`. But either way it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Avoid try if you require the info. Otherwise you'll have false positive